# Customized copy of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a customized class for which I would like to define a copy algorithm. One of the parameters should be the attribute for which I would like to have a deep copy, the rest of the attributes should be the same (such that when one is modified the other one is as well).

I have unsuccessfully written the below code:

```
from copy import deepcopy


class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._c = 1

    def copy(self, p):
        new = A()
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            if k == p:
                setattr(new, k, deepcopy(v))
            else:
                setattr(new, k, v)
        return new

a = A([1], [2])
b = a.copy('a')
b.a = [2]
a.b = [3]
```

I would expect:

```
print(a.a)  # = [1], which I get as expected
print(b.b)  # = [3], but i get [2] instead
```

I have also tried overriding `__deepcopy__` with no luck.

---

Surprisingly, with:

```
    def __copy__(self):
    new = A()
    new.a = deepcopy(self.a)
    new.b = self.b
    return new
```

I get

```
a = A([1], [2])
b = copy(a)
a.b is b.b  # True
a.b = [3]
print(b.b)  # = [2] why??
```

---

Is there any way to do this, should I be using a library to do that, or is simply my idea something that should not be done?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using `setattr()` rather than `new.k = v`?

Comment: k is a str, doing `new.k = v` will define the new attribute of b called "k" to be v, i.e. `b.__dict__` would produce `{'_c': 1, 'a': None, 'b': None, 'k': 1}`.